# HTML5 navigation and search engine optimization

Tags: seo, html5, nginx, angular.js

I'm trying to use HTML5 navigation for AngularJS application. Everything works well, until SEO optimisation. For hashbang sub-urls (`example.com/#!/siuburl`) most of crawlers (google, facebook) which cannot execute JS were doing replacement with `_escaped_fragment_` GET parameter (see [documentaton](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) - it is deprecated by still works). Nginx serever was configured to serve cached with phantomjs versions of pages when request contains `_escaped_fragment_`.

In case of HTML5 navigation there is no way to differ request from user and crauler's visit. I can see here two only solution possible:

1. respond with cached version by default, but refresh page with actual HTML5-navigated after small timeout
2. always use cached version, just replace all caches after release

Both options seems like dirty hacks for me. There is also an option to handle User Agent in Nginx, but it is not a good solution as well: crawler vendors can change user agent at any time. And I would also need to keep whole the list up-to-date.

Is there a common way to solve such HTML5+SEO+JS problem?

Comment: `there is no way to differ request from user and crauler` - useragent. This recognition method is common for prerendering of static HTML in case of React/Angular. Its true, it looks pretty like cloaking - but most use it without troubles.

Comment: and if your problem is SEO, you are likely to be concerned about two or three robots at most, and while those will be harder to change, any changes on their user agent can be easily fixed.